# プログラミング言語または英語圏の新語のリストを配布しているサイトを探しています

Tags: 単語辞書

プログラミング言語特有（function名など）の単語を収集し、dicファイルとして配布しているサイトを探しています。
あわせて、英語圏での新語（流行り言葉・スラング・プログラミング独特の言い回しなど）を集めたものも探しています。
プログラミング言語用の辞書作成プロジェクトなどあってよさそうなものですが、自分なりに探してみたところ見当たりませんでした。

用途としては、IDEやエディタなどでのスペルチェック時に使用する辞書に追加したいためです。
dicファイルといっても単純な文字の羅列ですので、形式はdicである必要はありません。

どなたかご存じないでしょうか？

Comment: どのような単語のリストを探しているのか、もう少し絞り込む（言語、目的、使用する命名規則などで）か、自分から単語リストの例や、使用されておられる辞書の種類を挙げられると、回答者が困ったり、回答がばらけないでよいのではないでしょうか。範囲が少し広いと思います。

Comment: 「辞書」タグだと、一般的なデータ構造としての辞書に関する質問と区別が付かなくなるため、「単語辞書」に変更しました。(「[言語資源と付き合う](http://www.slideshare.net/unnonouno/ss-13236436)」というスライドを参考にしました)

Comment: HiroshiYamamoto　様
御教示ありがとうございました。
IntelliJ Ideaでの辞書Typoチェックの元となるものが欲しかったので、かなり広い範囲でカバーしているものを探していました。
以後質問する際は、もう少し質問範囲を狭めるよう配慮したいと思います。ありがとうございました。
ento　様
タグ変更ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

辞書という形ではありませんが、プログラミング言語のキーワードや標準関数名などであれば、既存のシンタックスハイライトのライブラリや、シンタックスハイライトに対応したエディタのソースに含まれているため、それが利用出来るかもしれません。

- [GeShiのソース](https://github.com/GeSHi/geshi-1.0/blob/master/src/geshi/cpp.php)（シンタックスハイライトライブラリ）
- [AceEditorのソース](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/mode/c_cpp_highlight_rules.js) (シンタックスハイライトが行えるエディタ)

GeShi は `$language_data['KEYWORDS']` にキーワードが格納されているようなので、

```
<?php
require '/path/to/geshi-1.0/src/geshi/*.php';
foreach ($language_data['KEYWORDS'] as $keywords) {
    echo implode("\n", $keywords), "\n";
}
```

などとすれば、定義されたキーワードが出力できそうです。

Comment: シンタックスハイライトライブラリは思いつきませんでした。
GeShi、AceEditorともに後ほど確認してみます。
また、js実装でいくつか心当たりもありますので、そちらから抜き出し、重複分を削除するなどして対応してみたいと思います。

サンプルコードも載せていただきまして、大変助かりました。
他の方の投稿も大変参考になりましたが、madapaja様のものにチェックをつけさせていただきます。

Answer (score 3):

若干ずれている気もしますが、[codic - デベロッパーのためのネーミング辞書](http://codic.jp/)というWebサービスにて、内部で使用している辞書データを[CC BY-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.ja)のもとに`csv`として配布しています。

また、英語のスラングを扱うオンライン辞書サイトは数多く存在しますが、辞書データをまるごと配布しているところは少ないのではないかなと思います。代わりに`API`を用いてデータを収集できそうなサービスを探すのはどうでしょう。

例えば誰でも単語を登録できる英語スラング検索サイト[Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/)はプログラミングのスラングも散見します。(例:[foo](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=foo&defid=765064))
また、`API`を公開しており、これを利用するためのライブラリもいくつか見つかりました。(例:[mvrilo/urban](https://github.com/mvrilo/urban))
そのまま使わなくとも、収集ツールを作るときの参考にはなりそうです。

Comment: codic、以前見ていたのですが単語数が少ない時でして失念していました。
副産物といいますか、APIを公開してIntelliJ Ideaにも対応するとの情報も得られましたので、参考になりました。
とりあえずまとまっているものは現存しないようですので、自分で作成する際にUrban DIctionaryの方も参考にさせていただきます。
ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

関数やメソッドの命名に使える単語サイトのことかなと思い

- [codic - デベロッパーのためのネーミング辞書](http://codic.jp/)

を提示しようと思ったのですが、どうも違いますね^^;

ということで、 `programming terms dictionary` というキーワードでググって出てきたものを示しておきます。ただし、求めておられるものそのものは見当たりませんでした。

- [Computer programming terms](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/program.htm)
- [Appendix:Glossary of computer programming - Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary_of_computer_programming)
- [Appendix:Glossary of Java programming language terms - Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary_of_Java_programming_language_terms)
- [Glossary of operating systems terms - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_operating_systems_terms)
- [List of DOS commands - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DOS_commands)
- [List of object-oriented programming terms - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-oriented_programming_terms)

出来たものを探すのはなかなか難しいようです。
プログラミング言語からご自身で抜き出した方が早いような気もします^^;

Comment: 少しググラビリティが悪いジャンルでしたので、キーワード参考にさせていただきます。
他の方もおっしゃっているように、なにか別のライブラリやプログラミング言語から抜き出すのがよさようですので、自分でやってみて、できあがり次第CCで公開しようかと思います。
ありがとうございました。